# Вопрос относительно конструкции try-except

Tags: python

Есть конструкция такого типа:

```
while True:
    try:
       ....
    except:
       continue
```

Если сервер обрывает соединение, то скрипт его восстанавливает. Однако, если я выключаю wi-fi и снова его включаю, скрипт зависает.

Как поступить?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pumpetee/2021/Kuna/bot_v2_btcusd_sell.py", line 32, in <module>
    responses = requests.post(url , headers=headers).json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Сервер не успевает обработать запрос. Скрипт пытается вытащить значение, которое еще не было занесено в базу данных.

Comment: В первую очередь найти конкретную строку, в которой скрипт зависает. При чём тут try-except, непонятно

Comment: Добавьте какое-нибудь логирование и посмотрите, на чём именно виснет, в какой строке. А там уже нужно копать что там - може нужно таймаут соединения выставить, может ещё что.

Comment: Добавил ошибку.

Comment: добавьте код? как и где происходит responses = requests.post(url , headers=headers).json()?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, дело не в try-except: у вас ошибка говорит о том, что responses не может быть преобразован в json... Попробуйте проверять данные перед декодированием:

```
json_data = None
r = requests.post(url , headers=headers)
if r.status_code == 200
    json_data = r.json()
```

Comment: Это грамотное решение, но никак не мешает мне. Скрипт сам переподключается. И следующая итерация проходит без проблем. Вопрос в том, почему при отключении wi-fi скрипт не реагирует на `except`

Comment: так добавьте код?